# Converting nested dict from json into dataframe with values as columns

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a dict from json that where I aggregate survey results via a loop for each individual person that answered via an API and would like to convert it into a dataframe that uses the 'title' values as columns and then has all the answers of one person in one row.

This is what the raw results look like for one person that took part in the survey:

```
 {'0': {'title': 'What department do you work?',
    'results': {'0': '', '1': '', '2': '', '3': 'Unit D'}}, 
    '1': {'title': 'I can focus on clear targets?',
    'results': {'0': 'Yes', '1': '', '2': ''}}
```

This is how the dataframe should look like:

```
Result ID  |  What department do you work in? | I can focus on clear targets
    1      |  Unit D                          | Yes
```

I tried a few different options in pandas, but couldnt get the desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is one non empty value per person use nested dictionary comprehension with filtering:

```
d =  {'0': {'title': 'What department do you work?',
    'results': {'0': '', '1': '', '2': '', '3': 'Unit D'}}, 
    '1': {'title': 'I can focus on clear targets?',
    'results': {'0': 'Yes', '1': '', '2': ''}}}

df = pd.DataFrame({v['title']: [v1 for k1, v1 in v['results'].items() if v1] 
                   for k, v in d.items()})
print (df)
  What department do you work? I can focus on clear targets?
0                       Unit D                           Yes
```

If possible multiple values:

```
d =  {'0': {'title': 'What department do you work?',
    'results': {'0': '', '1': '', '2': '', '3': 'Unit D'}}, 
    '1': {'title': 'I can focus on clear targets?',
    'results': {'0': 'Yes', '1': 'No', '2': ''}}}


df = pd.DataFrame({v['title']: pd.Series([v1 for k1, v1 in v['results'].items() if v1])
                   for k, v in d.items()})
print (df)
  What department do you work? I can focus on clear targets?
0                       Unit D                           Yes
1                          NaN                            No
```

Comment: thanks for that quick indepth answer. The second option works like a charm for me! I really need to brush up my pandas knowledge seeing this! Thanks again.